# Composite function theorem for limits at infinity

Tags: calculus

The composite function theorem given in the Calculus book I am using (Calculus Volume 1 by openstax), is given for $x\to a$. The theorem is as given as follows. If $f(x)$ is continuous at $L$ and

$$ \lim \limits_{x \to a} g(x) = L $$

then we have

$$ \lim \limits_{x \to a} f(g(x)) = f( \lim \limits_{x \to a} g(x) ) = f(L) $$

But I would like to evaluate the limits like $ \exp(x)^2 $ as $x \to \infty $. So, this theorem does not apply here. So, how would I do this ?

Thanks

Comment: By $\exp{(x)}^2$ do you mean $(e^x)^2$ or $e^{x^2}$ ?

Comment: Are you asking for the explicit delta-epsilon style proof for this kind of limit, or what level of rigor do you want? In practice we can just say that $\exp(x)$ blows up for large $x,$ and $y^2$ blows up for large $y.$

Comment: Since you mentioned you are reading Calculus Volume $1$ by openstax, Section-$4.6$ of this book discusses Limits at Infinity. You might want to have a look at that section.

Comment: @StephenDonovan since the OP mentions the openstax textbook, I believe an intro level (without rigor) explanation is desirable.

Comment: Its $ e^{x^2}$ I meant. Sorry for misunderstanding. I am expecting intro level explanation. but with sufficient backing with good arguments. I wish to study real analysis in the future, so as much rigor as possible is good. Lot of Calculus books like Stewart's do not explain things properly. OpenStax being a open source book, I have high expectations from them.

Comment: We have $e^{x^2}  \ge x^2$ for all $x$.